# Accessing globals from node.js modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to separate some functions into a file named `helpers.js`, in which I have put the below shown  code. What should I do to access the `app` variable from inside my method in order to be able to fetch my config element named `Path`?

```
Helpers = {

    fs:   require('fs'),

    loadFileAsString: function(file) {
        return this.fs.readFileSync( app.set('Path') + file)+ '';
    }
}

module.exports = Helpers;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So from what I see you need the `app` variable form Express. You can send it as a function param to loadFileAsString, for ex:

**helpers.js**

```
Helpers = {

    ...

    loadFileAsString: function(file, app) {
        return this.fs.readFileSync( app.set('Path') + file)+ '';
    }
}

module.exports = Helpers;
```

**some_file.js**

```
app = express.createServer();
...
helpers = require('./helpers.js');
helpers.loadfileAsString(file, app);
```

If you want the app to be global though you can do that also: `global.app = app` and you can access app everywhere without sending it as a function param.